# Backbone Marionette Fetch a Collection to an Array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm a newbie in Backbone and Marionette, I'm so confused when try to call a Backbone Collection and convert it to an array.

**It's my Collection Code**

```
programming.module("Program", function(Program, programming, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    Program.salesM = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {

        }
    })

    Program.salesC = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Program.salesM
    })

    var data;
    var initializeData = function(){
        data = new Program.salesC([
            {
                id : "1",
                tanggal : "12/08/2016",
                produk : "T-Shirt",
                jumlah : "1"
            },
            {
                id : "2",
                tanggal : "12/08/2016",
                produk : "T-Shirt",
                jumlah : "2"
            },
            {
                id : "3",
                tanggal : "13/08/2016",
                produk : "Case",
                jumlah : "3"
            },
            {
                id : "4",
                tanggal : "13/08/2016",
                produk : "T-Shirt",
                jumlah : "2"
            },
        ])
    }

    var API = {
        getData : function(){
            if(data===undefined){
                initializeData();
            }
            return data;
        }
    }

    programming.reqres.setHandler("data:entities", function(){
        return API.getData();
    })


})
```

And here is a part code from another file to request the Collection

```
var dataChart = programming.request("data:entities");
console.info(dataChart.get("tanggal")
```

It's not error, But i confused a bit with that. I try to make `dataChart.get("tanggal")` but it return undefined

I try to get and fetch the Collection into this format but I can't

```
var tanggal = ['tanggal on id 1','tanggal on id 2','tanggal on id 3']
var jumlah = ['jumlah on id 1','jumlah on id 2','jumlah on id 3']
```

So confused. please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the collection propwrly in your dataChart variable.
Since in your initializeData you are adding an array of four members to new object of type Program.salesC, your data will contain four models of type Program.salesM.
In order to get the result you want to get you should use following

```
var tanggal = dataChart.pluck('tanggal');
var jumlah  = dataChart.pluck('jumlah ');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code returns `data` in `getData` function and it's a backbone collection, which eventually gets stored into `dataChart` variable.

If you would look at the [Backbone Collection Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) you'll see that:

> Collections are ordered sets of models.

`get` method of the collection returns the model with the specified `id` in the parameter of `get`.

Now if you'd try to access `dataChart.get( "tanggal" )`, you won't get what you're looking for, as `dataChart` is a **collection** and `tanggal` is an attribute of the **model** in the collection.

You might have to re-structure your code based on your needs, but let's say if you really want to access the `tanggal` property of the model, you can do `dataChart.at( 0 ).get( 'tanggal' )`, where `0` is the `index` of the model in the collection. Or you can utilize [these underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) available to the collection.